# AndroidStudio cant resolve classes from imported library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I ve got an Android App in which there is the app itself and a imported AndroidLibrary which consists of a JAR-Archive and a lib folder with additional classes.
The JAR-Archive is also in the app, but i want the Archive to be accessible through the library only.
The Problem here is that it builds on older Android Studio Versions just fine but on the latest it doesn t, i ve checked my dependencies and it seems like they re alright, but it s either not or Android Studio have some kind of a bug.

Is there any other way of fixing this than downgrading my Android Studio?

My dependecies are like followed:

app - build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/some.jar')
    implementation project(':intended-library')
}
```

library build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation files('libs/inteneded-jar-archive.jar') }
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':intended-library'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your library build.gradle file use api instead of implementation

```
dependencies {
 api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }) 

}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, it's now building again. Thank you!